# TFS and Mantis Integration

Tags: tfs, mantis, tfsintegrationplatform

I'd like to know if it's possible (and how, if anyone has ever done it before) to have Mantis Bug Tracker "tickets" automatically imported/transformed into TFS work items.

We use mantis to keep track of development and TFS as a Repo. Every check-in made to TFS must be associated with one work item. Right now, these two systems are not integrated which causes, for example, that the ticket 100 is relative to the work item 497 without no way of knowing that one is relative to the other.

I've looked at TFS Integration Tools but was unable to install it for some reason at this time.

So, how can I have an automation process that "imports" Mantis tickets into TFS work items automatically? Is this even possible?

Comment: Anything is possible. TFS Integration Tools are one way (you'll have to write a custom adapter). Building something yourself using the TFS Client Object Model is another. 3rd party tools like OpsHub might also work. Why do you say you can't use the Integration Tools?

Comment: Hi @jessehouwing. During installation it gives me an error relative to TFS Dev Tools or something similar. I haven't really give it too much attention at this time (other priorities) but I'll definetly have a look soon.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for source integration which supports Git, SVN and Mercurial (experimental).
https://github.com/mantisbt-plugins/source-integration

I am not aware that there is something similar avalaible for TFS, but it should be no big problem to implement TFS integration based on the framework which is offered by the plugin.